# SharePoint 2013 Visio document error: the server failed to process the request

Tags: sharepoint-2013, visio

When I try to open Visio documents uploaded to my SharePoint site, I get "the server failed to process the request" error. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps that I followed that fixed the issue:

1. Open SharePoint Central Administration on SharePoint server.
2. Manage service applications (under Application Management).
3. Select Visio Graphics Service -> Properties
4. Check what Application Pool is used (SharePoint Web Services Default in my case).
5. Open IIS -> Application Pools.
6. Visio App Pool is usually represented by a GUID name. To get the name:

   - Open SharePoint Management Shell (run as administrator)
   - Run command: Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | Select Id, Name
   - Find Id of App Pool (from step 4)
   - Find the same id in IIS under Name column and check the value in Identity column
7. Remote to the sql server
8. Open Sql Server Management Studio -> Connect
9. Expand the databases that stores your SharePoint content -> Security -> Users
10. Right click user name obtained in step 6d -> Properties
11. In Owned Schema and Membership check db_owner

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't mess with Database unless absolutely necessary.  Try this:

$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://contoso.com
$webApp.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("contoso\ServiceAppID")

Answer (score 0):

In our situation, there were errors in event log on the app and WFEs for a bunch of services including the Visio graphic service:

```
 System.IO.FileLoadException: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances
```

I went in to the Visio Graphics Service Settings > Global Settings and looked at the value in the Unattended Service Account, meaning it was registered with the secure store service. I went in to the secure store service and got the following error:

```
Cannot complete this action as the Secure Store Shared Service is not responding. Please contact your administrator
```

Recycling IIS on our app server resolved both the issues, so obviously the services having problems were a result of the secure store service being down.

Answer (score 0):

If in the Windows Events the following error is being logged:

> Failed to access the cache.

Then, on your SharePoint Web Front End servers, run the following command in the command prompt or PowerShell:

```
iisreset -noforce
```